# sql names containing 2 or more charaters

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a question for learning sense more than I need to find a solution.
I have a product entity, and it has an attribute of product_name. I would like to search product_name and return all products that have more than 1 'a' in the product_name. I need help with the query for this.

This code shows all products that have 'a'

```
SELECT product_name AS 'Product Names' FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
```

BUT I'm after products that have more than 1 'a'.
Structure: Product

```
Product(p_Id, product_name, p_cost)
```

So if I had a product called "Car Manual" it would return as there are 3 'a's.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query would look like:

```
SELECT product_name AS ProductNames
FROM product
WHERE name LIKE '%a%a%';
```

Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  The best thing to do is to name the columns so they don't need to be escaped.  Otherwise use backticks, double quotes, or square braces, depending on your database.

Comment: Thank you, was simpler than I imagined. I was thinking I had to use Count(). Thanks Again

Comment: So if I wanted to show products that 'a' for its second letter would it be:

Comment: underscore then a then %

Comment: @Jones . . . `name like '_a%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick you could use is to remove all 'a' characters in the name column and then check to see if the length has decreased by two or more:

```
SELECT product_name AS ProductNames
FROM product
WHERE LENGTH(REPLACE(name, 'a', '')) <= LENGTH(name) - 2
```

Comment: Is it an optimal approach? Compared to @Gordon Linoff's solution

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUddin Good question.  Gordon's approach _might_ perform slightly better, but MySQL could stop scanning the name as soon as it finds the second letter `a`.  My call to `REPLACE` will force MySQL to scan the entire name for `a`, regardless of how many times it appears.  Both solutions would scale the same as the table grew.